# ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Runnable command) when to create a new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am reading the source code of `ThreadPoolExecutor.java`, for the `execute` method below:

```java
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        if (command == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        /*
         * Proceed in 3 steps:
         *
         * 1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, try to
         * start a new thread with the given command as its first
         * task.  The call to addWorker atomically checks runState and
         * workerCount, and so prevents false alarms that would add
         * threads when it shouldn't, by returning false.
         *
         * 2. If a task can be successfully queued, then we still need
         * to double-check whether we should have added a thread
         * (because existing ones died since last checking) or that
         * the pool shut down since entry into this method. So we
         * recheck state and if necessary roll back the enqueuing if
         * stopped, or start a new thread if there are none.
         *
         * 3. If we cannot queue task, then we try to add a new
         * thread.  If it fails, we know we are shut down or saturated
         * and so reject the task.
         */
        int c = ctl.get();
        if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
            if (addWorker(command, true))
                return;
            c = ctl.get();
        }
        if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
            int recheck = ctl.get();
            if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
                reject(command);
            else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
                addWorker(null, false);
        }
        else if (!addWorker(command, false))
            reject(command);
    }
```

Assume the thread pool has 2 core threads and set the max pool size is 4.

I can understand the code `if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) { addWorkder(..) }`, it means if currently the core threads count is less than core poll size, just create a new thread to handle the runnable command.

What I cannot understand is, say if we had already called `execute(runnable)` two times, and each of them needs long time to complete, so they are still busy now, and now we are calling the 3rd time.

What the code will do? I think the code goes to `if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {` so the command gets added to work queue. However, I don't understand this 3rd command will be executed by which thread. As per the code `else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)`, I think worker count should be 2 because we have already added two workers.

So my question is when will the 3rd worker be added?

--Edit--

My testing code:

```
public class ThreadPoolExecutorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                2,
                4,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(4)
        );

        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Command("A"));
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Command("B"));
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Command("C"));

    }

    static class Command implements Runnable {
        private String task;
        Command(String task) {
            this.task = task;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 10);
                System.out.println(new Date() + " - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + task);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
Thu Jun 13 17:44:30 CST 2019 - pool-1-thread-1 : A
Thu Jun 13 17:44:30 CST 2019 - pool-1-thread-2 : B
Thu Jun 13 17:44:40 CST 2019 - pool-1-thread-1 : C
```

With the testing code I expect the core workers are keep being busy for 10 seconds so when `execute("C")` I want to hit the case 'core workers are busy and the 3rd worker will be added', but it seems that there is no the 3rd worker? Sorry but what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: *"What the code will do?"* I think a debugger can explain it better than us...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yep, I am trying now

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Debugging thread scheduling code with a debugger is really difficult. Extreme Heisenberg effects.

Comment: A third worker will only be added if the existing two are still busy. Otherwise one of them will pick up the task.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks, for pointing out `Otherwise one of them will pick up the task`. I think I could understand there is a loop for the core worker thread to get a work from the work queue, so `workQueue.offer(command)` will bring one of them up and they will handle the runnable. However, I still cannot understand when/how the 3rd worker will be added by reading the code. Thanks.

Comment: `addWorker(null, false)` will be called. This finds out if an additional non-core worker needs to be started (it does not do it unconditionally). There is code in there that checks on the existing workers status and on the queue. It is a complicated method, take a look.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks. `else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0).. addWorker(null, false);`. Isn't `workerCountOf(recheck)` returns 2 because there are 2 core workers are working? If it returns 2 how can `addWorker(null, false)` be called? Could you please explain more, thanks much!

Comment: @Thilo I edited the question with a testing code, could you please help to provide some points? Thanks much!

Comment: Good point. It seems the third worker is only created when the queue is full. Javadoc says "If there are more than corePoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full." @LiuWenbin_NO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to hit the case 'core workers are busy and the 3rd worker will be added'

Then you also have to fill up the queue.

Javadoc says:

> When a new task is submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable), and fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle. If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads running, **a new thread will be created only if the queue is full**.

Comment: `threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Command("A"));
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Command("B"));
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Command("C"));
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Command("D"));
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Command("E"));
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Command("F"));
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Command("G"));` This will hit the case to create the 3rd worker thread. A / B won't add to work queue. C/D/E/F fill up the work queue, so when executing G, it hits the logic `else if (!addWorker(command, false))`.

Comment: I have to say I also thought it would first add workers and then queue. But apparently not. You stay at the core worker size until you cannot queue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

```
   N = no of thread in currently in the pool.
   C = core size of pool
   M = maximum size of pool.
   BQ = Bounded Blocking Queue.(having a predefined capacity).
   UQ = Unbounded Blocking Queue.(without a predefined capacity).
   DHQ = Direct hand-offs Queue.
```

Then

```
       1. If BQ

           A. If N <= C , then thread always created when task is submitted, idle 
              thread is  present in pool or not doesn't matter.
           B. Once the core pool size is reached, executor start puting 
              the new task in queue if there is no idle thread. 
              If there is any idle thread then the task is assigned to idle thread.
           C. When BQ is full, then executor start creating again new thread till 
              its value reached to M if there is no idle thread.
              So the new thread creation after reaching N=C value is start when queue 
              is full.
           D. Once N=M reached and BQ is also full , then executor not accept any 
              task.It throw exception.

      2. If UQ 

           A. Same as above
           B. Same as above
           C. Not applicable. Why ? because it is unbounded queue.
              (UQ capacity is Integer.MAX_VALUE)
           D. No effect of M. Why ? 
              Since creation of new thread again is start after the queue is full,but 
              in the case UQ queue is never full. 
              So new thread never created once reach N=C for the new task submitted. 
              Means thread in thread pool always be equal to C (N=C always) in case 
              UQ , whatever the value of M


     3. If DHQ 
          A. The direct hand-offs queue never put the task in queue, its immediately
             assigned task to thread if any thread is idle ,if not then it create new 
             one.(task in queue is always 0)
          B. The concept of C is not applicable in this queue.Thread created till 
             its value reach M.
          C. Once the N value reach M (N=M), and try to submit the task ,it reject 
             the task.
```